# Instagram API view public user photo without access_token

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I am going to develop an app for a retailer and the client want to show its official instagram images in the app.

Its Instagram account is public and I see that, there is an API for retrieving user recent images.

[https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user_id}/media/recent?clent_id=XXXXX](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/%7Buser_id%7D/media/recent?clent_id=XXXXX)

The document have not stated that access_token is required but when I execute this api, it says I am missing access_token.

Is it normal or I did something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your requested URL is wrong, it will work only after correcting the '**client_id**' instead of '**clent_id**'.

Comment: This will not work anymore!! "We no longer support making requests using just the client_id." (https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)